# Opt out of SwiftUI Text Markdown Support in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, markdown

let's say I want to show the following text to the user in `Text`:

```
3+4*5, 6*7+8
```

The new SwiftUI behavior in iOS 15 will render this string in Markdown, making the center part italic.

See here: [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-render-markdown-content-in-text)

I could do this and it works on iOS 15:

```
Text("3+4\\*5, 6\\*7+8")
```

but on iOS 14, it will display as the following due to the lack of Markdown parsing:

```
3+4\*5, 6\*7+8
```

Is there a way to opt out of Markdown parsing so I can target iOS 15 and 14 with a single string?

Comment: Swift (and other programming languages use one ` \ ` as an escape statement. So for your problem. Removing one ` \ ` ought to do the trick

Comment: One ‘\’ wouldn’t work because the compiler complains that ‘*’ is not an escapable character

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the initializer that you use, will depend on whether it will render markdown or not. You don't need to use escape characters, you just have to set up your strings in the correct way.

Here is a break down of how you can have or not have markdown with or without localization.

1. If you use the default `Text()` and pass a string straight to it then it will assume that you are passing a `LocalizedStringKey` and it will localize it and render it with mark down. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:tablename:bundle:comment:)).
2. If you have your string as a variable then SwiftUI will use the `Text()` initializer where you are using an actual `String` and it will render it without localization and no markdown. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-9d1g4).
3. If you use `Text(verbatim:)` then it will use no localization and no markdown. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(verbatim:)).
4. If you want to use localization but no markdown then you need to create a localizedString using `String(localized:)` and then pass that to the `Text()`. You can read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3867985-init).

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let stringVariable = "This is *markdown*"

    let localizedString = String(localized: "This is *markdown*")

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {

            // 1
            // Localization with markdown
            // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:tablename:bundle:comment:)
            Text("This is *markdown*")

            // 2
            // No localization no markdown
            // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-9d1g4
            Text(stringVariable)

            // 3
            // No localization no markdown
            // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(verbatim:)
            Text(verbatim: "This is *markdown*")

            // 4
            // This is a localized string but no markdown
            // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3867985-init
            Text(localizedString)
        }
    }
}
```

The above produces the following

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create the `Text` using the `verbatim` initializer:

```
Text(verbatim: “1*2 = 2*1”)
```

This is supported from iOS 13 and will bypass all conversions and localizations.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(verbatim:)